# Force uninstall

Tags: windows, installation

I have an app that does not uninstall. It requires the installer file to uninstall, but I can't find it. So, how can I force the uninstallation of an application?

Thank you

Comment: I've found no solution to this - but a bit more information ...

Sometimes when a program installs it ends up putting the "uninstall" in the users profile - for example "administrator".  If that profile is then removed then the uninstaller goes as well, which then means it won't uninstall without it.

Comment: Good question, but belongs over at superuser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help greatly if you told us the app name and what windows flavor you're using.  Usually if you have old files and reg settings that need to be cleared-out [**ccleaner**](http://www.ccleaner.com/) (freeware) does the trick.

I've also heard good things about [**Revo Uninstaller**](http://www.revouninstaller.com/index.html) (freeware)

### update

Also, specific for your problem, there is a technote at the adobe site for an **uninstaller for Adobe Flash:** [**http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html**](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html)

Comment: its macromedia flash player 8 in a vista machine, although I would prefer something that would work with other cases.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly it really does depend what application it is, some apps like Norton have an application you can download to remove the application, so its worth checking that.

If that doesn't work then the apps that l0c0b0x suggested will often fix this problem for you.

Finally if that doesn't work, you will need to manually remove the files for the application and then manually remove their entrys from the registry.

**Usually warning that editing your registry can break your PC, always backup beforehand**

The three most common places for applicaiton data to be stored are:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE.
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE.
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ CURRENTCONTROLSET\SERVICES

-EDIT

As SeanyBoy points out, the uninstaller for Norton can be found [here](http://service1.symantec.com/Support/tsgeninfo.nsf/docid/2005033108162039)

Comment: Norton has an application you can download to uninstall it!!! Where can I find this?

Comment: Found it. http://service1.symantec.com/Support/tsgeninfo.nsf/docid/2005033108162039

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is to re-download the application, reinstall the program, and then uninstall it.

Comment: Or upgrade the application, and then uninstall it